# How to automatically run Android when battery level exceeds some level?

Tags: android, battery, android-reboot

I have a problem with my Android tablets (Samsung Note P-900, P-905), my customers often turn off the electricity in their shops and tablets are discharged, and of course they don't turn on again. I found a solution to turn it on automatically when they are plugged in, unfortunately, that is not enough. I need to run it when the battery level exceeds level about 5%.
This is my code for auto turning on:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
su
/system/bin/reboot
```

I put these 3 lines into /system/bin/lpm (can be different filename in other versions). So, friends, do you know how to run Android when battery exceeds some level?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as I know an automatic power up can only be done in the boot loader (which is usually closed source). But what's the point in turning on a device when the power drops below 5% anyway? they will discharge only faster.

Comment: The point is when tablet turns on at 0% battery it turns off and on again and again. When it wait for 5% it turns on and doesn't discharging, but charging.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I think OP wants to turn the device back on once it has charged to 5%.

Comment: well, in that state only the boot loader is active. as long as you don't find an open replacement for that you're out of luck.

Comment: @Gumbo exactly, you are right

Comment: One thing I can think of: Check regularly the battery charge and if it is plugged in or not. If it is unplugged and/or the charge is below X (and maybe check the time too, your customers most probably turn the electricity off over night) do a clean shutdown. That way the devices shouldn't discharge over night and will turn on properly in the morning.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider I'm afraid that this is the only solution. I was googling and found only one app "Auto ShutDown when no charge" which is not free. Do you know any costless way?